# iOS put HTML text in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

I need to put HTML text with bold,italic and links in a UILabel.
If I use `NSAttributedString` the links aren't clickable. If I use `TTTAttributedLabel` links are clickable but the formatting (bold and italic) is not visibile.

This problem drive me crazy! Ideas?

Comment: You can check [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) whether it helps or not?

Comment: Are you able to use UITextView instead of a UILable? I'm not sure, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the link formatting work using TTTAttributedLabel.  For example, this will color links blue and underline them (in Swift):

```
let bodyLabel: TTTAttributedLabel

let content = "TTTAttributedLabel will detect http://example.com"
let attributedContent = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content)

// add some attributes as you need to the attributed string, then...

let blueLinks = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]

bodyLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue
bodyLabel.linkAttributes = blueLinks

bodyLabel.setText(attributedContent)
```